# How to mount with SAMBA and respect symlinks

Tags: linux-networking, samba, file-sharing, symlink

I am mounting a directory, e.g., `/home/docs/` from PCserver to PCclient using the SAMBA share in Linux. Both computers are in Linux (Ubuntu).

I perform `sudo mount -f cifs` with the necessary parameters, and everything works okay. The `/home/docs/` from PCserver is mounted in PCclient.
The problem is that the **symlinks** of the PCserver, either *files* or *directories*, are not mounted as *symlinks*, but as *target* files or directories.

How can I mount symlinks of the *server* als symlinks in the *client*, using samba?

I have tried in the `smb.conf` file the option `follow symlinks = no`. The only result is that folders als symlinks cannot be opened in the PCclient, but symlink files are mounted as the target files and not as symlinks.

I have found a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/170964/cant-create-or-follow-symlinks-from-linux-client-with-a-cifs-mounted-windows-se). But no clear solution is given.

Comment: Can you the output of `mount | grep "/home/docs"` executed on a client to your question. I guess this includes `nounix` or `noposix` or `nolinux`. You could try to mount with `mount -t cifs -o ...,linux` option, I did test this but did not succeed. Not sure if that is related to my setup.

Answer (score 1):

If both computers run on Linux, we can rather set up an **NFS Mount** (See [how to set it up](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04)), instead of SAMBA. This mount respects the original *symlinks* as they are in the PCServer.

Comment: This helped me to fix the copying of repo project with rsync.

Comment: @LVitya Ha, ha, you got me! I found this option as I was insistently searching for a way to copy symlinks using rsync. Glad to help you. Be blessed!